# ROR syntax error unknown attribute: email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add data to the buyer in the user model and the console shows an error

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: email
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
    from (irb):8
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

write here is what

```
u = User.create( login: "weare138", email: "readfuzza@gmail.com", password: "qwertyqwerty", password_confirmation "qwertyqwerty" )
```

my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

#devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

   attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

   has_one :cart
   has_many :orders
end
```

Here is my migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :login
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: does your users table have an email column ?

Comment: Did you run your migration?

Answer (score 1):

Check your DB and make sure the email column is present under User. If not, then create a rake migration that adds the email column to user.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` is telling you that you are trying to construct a User with an attribute the database doesn't know about (although it is defined in your model).

Answer (score 0):

Running migration should solve problem:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: @weare138, what doesn't work, migration? Can you give more context.
Can you go to rails console with `rails c` and type User. You will get all user attributes. It will help to resolve problem.